# 'ng new my-app' error

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, command-line-interface

I am trying to generate a new project and skeleton application using the latest version of Angular. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling Angular CLI using:

```sh
C:\>npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

```sh
C:\>ng --version

@angular/cli: 1.4.5
node: 8.8.1
os: win32 x64
```

This error occurs when trying to run 'ng new my-app' in command prompt:

```sh
'Error: The command "new" has an option without the required type and name field'
```

Any help to resolve this issue is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a known issue and there is an issue raised in github for this.

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7984

Try below commands:

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Answer (score 1):

After these steps:

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Do:

```
npm install @schematics/angular
```

And then:

```
ng new appname
```