# ng new my-app fails to create a skeleton app

Tags: angular, npm

- I have installed npm version `5.6.0`
- I have installed angular/cli version `7.3.0`
- node version `v8.9.4`

When I run `ng new my-app` I get the error after I choose default CSS the error as below
`Invalid rule result: Instance of class Promise.`

Tried looking into this help
['ng new my-app' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47020670/ng-new-my-app-error)

Did not work for me

```
C:\NPMProjects\Angular>ng new my-app
? Would you like to add Angular routing? No
? Which stylesheet format would you like to use? CSS
Invalid rule result: Instance of class Promise.

C:\NPMProjects\Angular>
```

I expect app created in my folder `C:\NPMProjects\Angular` as `my-test` folder

Comment: accept the routing, and try once

Comment: This happened to me for a while and it worked if I didn't add hyphens in the app name, but failed if there were hyphens. Try ng new myapp, all one word, and see if it works. I didn't do anything to fix it; after a couple weeks it just started working again.

Comment: @ram12393 I tried that too, just choose all defaults but it fails at CSS, tried SCCS still the same error

Comment: @pjlamb12 tried this out just now, did not work same error ```ng new testApp```

Answer (score 0):

Can you double check that you are using Angular 7? I am seeing this error when trying to use create a new app with Angular 8 while running node 8.9.4 . I would try uninstalling angular then reinstalling angular7

Comment: I am using Angular  CLI 7.3.0, confirmed

Comment: Angular CLI: 7.3.0
Node: 8.9.4
OS: win32 x64
Angular:
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.13.0
@angular-devkit/core         7.3.0
@angular-devkit/schematics   7.3.0
@schematics/angular          7.3.0
@schematics/update           0.13.0
rxjs                         6.3.3

Comment: sorry I don't know how to beautify that above comment